# Dashboard of Kubernetes in Azure keeps disconnecting with error "an error occurred forwarding 8001 -> 9090"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-dashboard

I have very bad experience with using Kubernetes dashboard in Azure installed by [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-dashboard). It becomes unresponsive all the time. The reasons vary:

- When you do not touch the dashboard for couple minutes, it becomes unresponsive.
- When you open a live log feed from a pod, the parent dashboard browser tab becomes unresponsive.
- When you open an exec terminal in a pod, it becomes unresponsive at the very momenty I close the web terminal window.
- Sometimes it just stops working in a middle of browsing.

> Definig "unresponsive": The dashboard seems alive but when you click anything, nothing happens. Browser reloads the page but there is still the same content even if you click on different menu item.

I'm running the dashboard with a command from MSFT wiki:

```
az aks browse -g <cluster RG> -n <cluster name>
```

In the effect you have to re-run `az aks browse` every wonderful minute. Yes, you still can use it. But its *very* frustrating and its *really* a pain in the *** when you have to restart the `az aks browse` process every time after you use it for one purpose.

When the frontend goes down, the console log is full of this messages, like:

> E1106 00:08:08.555527    2927 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8001 -> 9090: error forwarding port 9090 to pod XXXXXX, uid : exit status 1: 2019/11/05 23:08:08 socat[31975] E connect(6, AF=2 127.0.0.1:9090, 16): Connection refused

Do you have similar experince?
Is there something that I can do about it?

---

OSX 10.14.6

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @PhoneixS Unfortunately, with kubernetes-dashboard, I did not. Instead I started using [K8Dash](https://github.com/herbrandson/k8dash) - faster, more reliable, quicker setup, lightweight and with realtime updates - and unlike kubernetes-dashboard - it does not have ton of bugs.

Comment: No problem, I have found that the problem is that after upgrading Kubernetes it also has updated the dashboard and I think that Microsoft hasn't updated the azure CLI to accommodate to the new protocol. I have to enter manually (port foward) and use a token to log in.